# EditText in dialog returning null string

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialog

I have this `button` to show a `dialog` which in turn has an `EditText` for the users to write something and then tap the `done` button to save it otherwise another `button` to close the `dialog`. The problem here is that I am not able to fetch that `String` that the user wrote. It returns me a null sting instead and causes the app to crash. Here's the code :

I call the `dialog` up on clicking on a button:

```
        //Write Review Dialog Box

    writeReviewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("HAPPENED", "This Onclick is working");
            try{

                // Create custom dialog object                    
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(GetReviewActivity.this);
                // Include dialog's xml file                    
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.write_review_activity);
                // Set dialog title                    
                dialog.setTitle("Your review is valuable");

                final EditText etWR = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etWR);

                Button writeButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonWR);

                Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonNoThanks);

                dialog.show();

                //Done Button
                writeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.i("HAPPENED: ","writeButton Block Is WORKING!");
                         Activity activity = GetReviewActivity.this;
                        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                String Review = etWR.getText().toString();
                                StoreAReview(Review);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Close dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have just forgot to find EditText from dialog reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`final EditText etWR = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etWR);` is resolving to `Activity#findViewById`. But your dialog's layout is not attached to your activity window, it's attached to the dialog. so you have to inflate `EditText` from your dialog's view:

Try

```
final EditText etWR = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.etWR);
```

instead of

```
final EditText etWR = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etWR);
```

Answer (score 3):

Been through this issue before. I tried initiating `EditText` with `Dialog` reference but this didn't work

```
final EditText etWR = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.etWR);
```

**Solution:**

This is how I solved it:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View dialogWR = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.write_review_activity, null);
    etWR = (EditText) dialogWR.findViewById(R.id.etWR);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize `EditText`

```
 EditText etWR = (EditText)dailog.findViewById(R.id.etWR);
```

becoz your `EditText`  is coming from `dailog`. So

Answer (score 0):

U just miss the  **dialog.findViewById(R.id.etWR)**

**change this line**

```
 final EditText etWR = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etWR);
```

**to this one**

```
final EditText etWR = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.etWR);
```

then, add click event code